"X is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint" for void function
I have a React Context where a function takes in another function as an argument. A generic hook then uses this.
// Context
export type A = { id: string }

const TestProvider = () => {
  function test(doStuff: (a: A) => void) {...}
  return <TestContext.Provider value={{test}}>{children}</TestContext.Provider>
}

// Hook
export function useThing<T extends A>() {
  const { test } = useContext(TestContext)
  const [stuff, setStuff] = useState<T[]>()

  function doStuff(a: T) {
    setStuff([...stuff, a])
  }

  function doMoreStuff() {
    test(doStuff) // The error occurs here
  }
}

I've looked at a lot of posts with this same problem, but they all have some sort of return value. How do I fix this for a function that returns nothing?
If I change the function signature in the hook to doStuff(a: Pick<T, 'id'>), the error disappears. However, this will cause an error in the setter function:

Type 'T | Pick<T, "id">' is not assignable to type 'T'.
'T | Pick<T, "id">' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'A'.


You should use your test function with generics, this way you can avoid this error, check this link here

You can fix this by correctly aligning the types. Add type the test function in the TestProvider component so that it accepts the generic type from the hook
I have updated your code below to explain what i mean:
// Context
export type A = { id: string }

type TestContextType<T extends A> = {
  test: (doStuff: (a: T) => void) => void;
};

const TestContext = React.createContext<TestContextType<A> | undefined>(undefined);

const TestProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  function test<T extends A>(doStuff: (a: T) => void) {...}

  return (
    <TestContext.Provider value={{ test }}>
      {children}
    </TestContext.Provider>
  );
};

// Hook - using the context type
export function useThing<T extends A>() {
  const context = useContext(TestContext);

  if (!context) {
    throw new Error("useThing must be used within a TestProvider");
  }

  const { test } = context;
  const [stuff, setStuff] = useState<T[]>([]);

  function doStuff(a: T) {
    setStuff([...stuff, a]);
  }

  function doMoreStuff() {
    test(doStuff);
  }
}

Hope this helps!
